# Android AVD emulator is not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

While launching Android AVD emulator via Android Studio. I'm getting this:-

[image]

My System Framework is 32-bit.Plz Help me I'm new in this..

Comment: @varchar, My system framework is 32...

Comment: Have you tried using the `-force-32bit` option when invoking the emulator? And did you set the `ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT` to `true` in your environment?

Comment: @DerGolem, I have tired -force-32bit. But its not working...gedit .profile  
From a terminal. Add the text:

export ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT=true  
to the end of the file and save and close it.  run source .profile from the terminal or restart for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Yes, a restart of the IDE is required.

Comment: @DerGolem, I have tried this. But its not working. Any other way if you have then please suggest me..

Comment: Are you using a 32 bit OS on a 32 bit CPU (make sure these match)? If not, just install the proprer version of Android Studio (64 bit)

Answer (score 1):

Can u take a workaround if you navigate until (in Android Studio embebed prompt):

`/home/ubuntu/Android/Sdk/tools/`

And when u are there executing:

`./emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_4_API_21_x86 -force-32bit`

Aproximately; i don't know what is your avd id, but maybe could be that prompt :P `-force-32bit` paramenter should make works ur emulator. Ideally u should change `ANDROID_EMULATOR_FORCE_32BIT` to true but i don't know where is that variable in Android Studio xD :)